# File name too long: Cannot map GET, ignores .htaccess ErrorDocument 403

Tags: apache, .htaccess, errordocument

I am using an Apache 2.2 server, and have a `.htaccess` file in my document root with the following content:

```
ErrorDocument 403 /index.php
```

Though when I access the server with a long GET URL (e.g. request `http://example.com/long/long/long/long/.../url`), a `403` forbidden response is returned. Therefore, my `.htaccess` `ErrorDocument` is ignored.

The apache_error.log contains:

```
[Mon May 09 08:14:16 2016] [error] [client ::1] (63)File name too long: Cannot map GET /long/long/long/long/long/long/long/longlong/long/long/longlong/long/long/longlong/long/long/longlong/long/long/longlong/long/long/longlong/long/long/long/.../url HTTP/1.1 to file
```

As I understood, the server ignores the `.htaccess` file when it receives a too long GET URL and therefore per-directory `ErrorDocument 403 /index.php` is ignored.
If I put the `ErrorDocument` directive inside of my local server's main config (httpd.conf, I tested it locally), everything works and `/index.php` is executed for this type of requests, so I can send a custom page.

However, I would like to handle that type of request with a custom page using an .htaccess as I don't have access to the remote server's main config file.

Can I do it somehow?

Comment: Apache sends a 414 error status to client if uri is too long. Why are you using 403 instead ?

Comment: I am not using 403, it seems that Apache returns a 403 for this. Should I check something inside of my local httpd.conf?

Comment: @starkeen https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=45187 Here a 403 forbidden error is returned for `File name too long` too